# Can't change a single value of an array created with fill method

Tags: javascript, arrays, fill

I created an array using Array and fill however after that I cannot edit a single value of this.

```
 const board = new Array(4).fill(Array(4).fill(0))


 board[0][0] = 1
```

This changes first index of every nested array.

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

So it isn't correct to create multidimensional array this way?

Comment: Because the `fill` function will re-use the passed array, so every position in the array will point to the same value in memory.